# Firebase query does not work correctly when it depends on the ArrayList Size()

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

From every query, I'm fetching information of 1 user. Here are 3 queries. The last 2 queries depend on the list size that comes from the previous query. But every query results in fetching 1 user in the list although there are 3 users to be showed and goes to the next method although it has been restricted.

I restricted by using a variable `count` but it also does not work. Restricting like this just puts 1 user in the ArrayList and then, goes to the next method like the previous scenario.

```
public class FriendsLeaderboardFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<Leaderboard> mLeaderboardList;
private ArrayList<String> mFollowing;
private ArrayList<UserPublicInfo> mUserPublicInfoList;
private int pos;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends_leaderboard, container, false);
    Log.d("TAG","FriendsLeaderboardFragment");
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mLeaderboardList = new ArrayList<>();
    mFollowing = new ArrayList<>();
    mUserPublicInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

    getInfo();

    return view;
}

private void getInfo() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child("following")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                mFollowing.add(singleSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue().toString());
            }
            mFollowing.add(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
            Log.d("getInfo",mFollowing.toString());
            getUserInfo();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void getUserInfo() {
    //get the profile image and username
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    for(int i=0; i<mFollowing.size(); i++){
        final int count = i;
            Query query = reference
                    .child("User Public Info")
                    .orderByChild("user_id")
                    .equalTo(mFollowing.get(i));
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: found user: "
                                + singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getUsername());
                        UserPublicInfo userPublicInfo = new UserPublicInfo();
                        userPublicInfo.setFollowing(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getFollowing());
                        userPublicInfo.setHometown(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getHometown());
                        userPublicInfo.setLongitude(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getLongitude());
                        userPublicInfo.setUsername(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getUsername());
                        userPublicInfo.setNumber_of_travelled_places(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getNumber_of_travelled_places());
                        userPublicInfo.setProfile_photo(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getProfile_photo());
                        userPublicInfo.setFollowers(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getFollowers());
                        userPublicInfo.setLatitude(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getLatitude());
                        userPublicInfo.setPosts(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getPosts());
                        userPublicInfo.setUser_id(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserPublicInfo.class).getUser_id());
                        mUserPublicInfoList.add(userPublicInfo);
                    }
                    if (count >= mFollowing.size() - 1){
                        Log.d("getUserInfo",mUserPublicInfoList.toString());
                        getPointCount();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
}

private void getPointCount() {
    Log.d("getPointCount",mUserPublicInfoList.toString());

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    for(int i=0; i<mUserPublicInfoList.size(); i++){
            Query query = reference
                    .child("User Photos")
                    .child(mUserPublicInfoList.get(i).getUser_id())
                    .child("Uploaded");
            final int count = i;
            pos = i;

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    List<Like> likesList = new ArrayList<Like>();
                    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                                .child("likes").getChildren()){
                            Like like = new Like();
                            like.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id());
                            likesList.add(like);
                        }
                    }
                    if (count >= mUserPublicInfoList.size() - 1){
                        inflateView();
                    }
                    else{
                        int size = likesList.size();
                        Leaderboard leaderboard = new Leaderboard();
                        leaderboard.setUsername(mUserPublicInfoList.get(pos).getUsername());
                        leaderboard.setProfile_photo(mUserPublicInfoList.get(pos).getProfile_photo());
                        leaderboard.setUser_id(mUserPublicInfoList.get(pos).getUser_id());
                        leaderboard.setPoints(String.valueOf(size));
                        mLeaderboardList.add(leaderboard);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
}

private void inflateView() {
    Log.d("getPointCount",mUserPublicInfoList.toString());
    listView.setAdapter(new LeaderboardItemAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_friends_leaderboard,mLeaderboardList));
}
}
```

I expect that each query results in getting all list and then go to the next method as the last 2 query depends on the previous ArrayList size().

Comment: Share your debug logs.

Comment: can you log the mFollowing.size() in `getUserInfo`?